# Show dependencies for one configuration

Tags: gradle

How to show dependencies only for one configuration? Command `gradle dependencies` shows dependencies for all configurations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do so by providing the command line parameter `--configuration`. Example for a Java project:

```
gradle dependencies --configuration compile
```